# Merge delimited data files with KML files

Tags: file-merging, kml

I use Google Fusion Tables to merge KML map files with data files. "TractID" is the column the KML file and any given data file has in common.

What desktop program or command line tool can I use to easily merge data files with KML files?

OS: Windows 10 or Debian 9.

Comment: Are competent to code? There are libraries for Python.

Comment: I@EricShain  which libraries?

Comment: pyKML for one, but there are others. Try a Google search. I haven’t used any of them so I can’t make a recommendation.